# need help in my jQuery functions. last line code is first called even if not ajax

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

On initialisation the alert("last") is first called while the alert("loop") is the last called.

```
$(strclass).prepend('<div class="mytabheader"></div>')
  .find(".mytabbody").each(function(){
    theid=theid+1;
    var thecaption = $(this).attr("caption").replace(/\s/gi,"");
    var addtocaption = $(this).attr("addtocaption")==undefined?addtocaption="":addtocaption=addtocaption;

    $(this).parentsUntil("",".mytab")
      .find(".mytabheader")
      .append('<div class="mytabfragmentscaption" id="fragments'+theid+'">'+addtocaption+$(this).attr("caption")+'</div>');
    var thisel = this;
    $(this).parentsUntil("",".mytab")
      .find("#fragments"+theid)
      .on('click',function(){               
        $(this).parentsUntil("",".mytab")
          .find(".mytabfragmentscaption")
          .removeClass("active");

        $(strclass).find(".mytabbody").css("display","none");
        $(thisel).css("display","table");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        alert("loop");
        if(arr[$(this).attr("id")]!=undefined){
          arr[$(this).attr("id")]();
        }
      });
  });
  alert("last");

  $(strclass).find(".mytabheader")
    .find("#fragments1")
    .trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alert('loop')` is in a click handler, which is triggered by `.trigger('click')` right at the end of your snippet.